# What does this VimL regular expression mean? %[MRHWY]

Tags: vim

I see some viml code like

```
if &foo =~# '%[MRHWY]' && &foo !~# '%[mrhwy]'
```

What do those strings `'%[MRHWY]'` and `'%[mrhwy]'` mean? Do they mean something in context of the `=~#` comparison that may be different from another context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case sensitive (`=~#`) pattern matching to a collection, `[]`. In this instance, it is matching on `%` and a collection of letters which may show up in one's statusline. Specifically:

`%[MRHWY]` can match '`%M`', '`%R`', '`%H`', '`%W`', or '`%Y`'.

What may distract you, as it did for me, is that there is also a sequence pattern match, `%[]`, which matches as much of the collection as it can; its routine stops at the first atom that doesn't match (see help %[] vs. [] for more examples and details). However, this is just not the case here, since there is a quote before `%`, in front of a collection.

With a quick search, I see this line of code is used in the fugitive.vim package where it checks the status line for the sequence of letters 'MRHWY':

```
function! fugitive#statusline(...) abort
  if !exists('b:git_dir')
    return ''
  endif
  let status = ''
  if s:buffer().commit() != ''
    let status .= ':' . s:buffer().commit()[0:7]
  endif
  let status .= '('.fugitive#head(7).')'
  if &statusline =~# '%[MRHWY]' && &statusline !~# '%[mrhwy]'
    return ',GIT'.status
  else
    return '[Git'.status.']'
  endif
endfunction
```

(BTW: If  you want to see what these letters each mean, see help :statusline. An example: M is modified text flag, R is readonly flag, etc.)

Comment: A Sequence is `\%[]`, `[MRHWY]` is a collection. `%` is there because statusline items are printf style. `&statusline =~# '%[MRHWY]'` means if statusline option value is include any of `%M` or `%R` or `%H` or `%W` or `%Y`